# WordPress Register JSON Endpoint - Which PHP File?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to stand up a new RESTful endpoint to receive POSTed JSON.  I found some documentation, but conspicuously missing from all docs is any reference to a .php file where this needs to go.  Where should the call to register_rest_route go?  Is there an existing file?  Or do I need a new one?

I'm seeing some references to that function in wp-includes/class-wp*.php...so are you supposed to find one of those files to add your custom endpoint to?  Or create a new file under wp-includes?  I don't do much WordPress customization.

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a [plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and put it there. Or if it's a custom theme, you could put it in functions.php. You don't want to change any WordPress files (like wp-includes) because they will get overwritten whenever you update WordPress, and if it's not your theme, then putting something in functions.php will get overwritten if the the theme is ever updated. If you're just looking for a quick fix, you could put your code in the [mu-plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) folder in the root of the wp-content directory (or create it if it doesn't exist). Then you would just need to add an action to the correct hook:

```
function my_api_endpoint_test() {
  register_rest_route('my-namespace/v2', '/test', array(
    'methods'  => 'POST',
    'callback' => function($data) {
      return rest_ensure_response('test');
    }
  ));
}
add_action('rest_api_init', 'my_api_endpoint_test');
```